# json-editor ignores starting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plugins, schema

I am trying to utilize https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor.  I have read all documentation and examples multiple times and I cannot get the editor to respect my starting values (startVal).  The editor is created using my schema, but the editor is not initialized with the starting object I am providing.  Here is my code:

```js
  $.get("/AppAdmin/GetWorkflowEditSchema", {}, function (schemaResponse) {

      if (schemaResponse) {

        var editSchema = JSON.parse(schemaResponse);

        $.get("/AppAdmin/GetWorkflow?workflowName=" + workflowToEdit, {}, function (workflowResponse) {

          if (workflowResponse)
          {
            var workflow = JSON.parse(workflowResponse);

            const holder = document.getElementById("workflowEditorHolder");

            var options = {
              "schema": editSchema,
              "startVal": workflow,
              "theme": "bootstrap4"
            };
    
            jsonEditor = new JSONEditor(holder, options);
          }
          else {
            toastr.error("The workflow could not be loaded to edit.");
          }
        });

      }
      else {
        toastr.error("Reading edit schema failed.");
      }
```

Both server responses are the correct JSON strings.  When I copy and paste my schema and starting object into the json-editor interactive playground at https://pmk65.github.io/jedemov2/dist/demo.html, the editor is created with the correct starting values.  So I suspect something is wrong with my objects.  I am very unfamiliar with JSON so that would not be surprising.

Here is my schema:

[image: schema]

And the object I am trying to initialize the editor with:

[image: object]

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using setValue() after creation instead of passing the initializing object:

```js
            var options = {
              "schema": editSchema,
              // "startVal": workflow,
              "theme": "bootstrap4"
            };
    
            jsonEditor = new JSONEditor(holder, options);
            jsonEditor.setValue(workflow);
```